# Add UILabel as a constant field to left of UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am facing on problem, I want to have a static text in UITextField.

Text like "UserName:" should appear constantly to the left side of UITextField. Editing the UITextField should start from where the "UserName:" text ends.

For example, in iPhone settings, if we go to Twitter app and try to add new account. The way the user name and password textfield looks like. I want to develop same like that.

Comment: Try with, UITabelViewCell with UILabel & UITextField .. you need to do some design sketch to get it (mimic).

Comment: Thank @KumarKL for quick reply. No, I don't want to use UITableViewCell for that. Is there any other solution.

Comment: @KumarKL do you have any tutorial to use UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand why everyone has has posted such *off the track* answers to such a simple issue.

You simply do this:

- Create a `UILabel`, with UI complimenting you `textField`.
- You set it's text (**Username:**, etc).
- Assign it to your `textField`'s `leftView` property.

That's it. You will have to check frames, but that is basic, and I believe you can do that without much effort.

**UPDATE:** Sample code

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
UITextField* aField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 300, 40)];    
aField.placeholder = @"Please enter a username";    
aField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;    
aField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];    
aField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;    
aField.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;    

UILabel* aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 38)];    
aLabel.text = @"Username:";    
aLabel.font = aField.font;    
aLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];    

aField.leftView = aLabel;    
aField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;    

[self.view addSubview:aField];
```

Only needs minor adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two text fields (one partially overlap with other) or Implement the below code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   yourTextField.text = @"UserName:";
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

      //handle back spaces and error conditions

      NSString *editedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

      if([editedText isEqualToString: @"UserName"])
      {
        return NO;
      }
      else
      {
          yourTextField.text =  editedText;
          return YES;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code may cater your need.

```
UIView *vis = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 50)];

UILabel *lblUserName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 120, 40)];


UITextField *txtUserName =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 5, 180, 40)];
lblUserName.text= @"User Name";
txtUserName.placeholder = @"@User Name";
[vis addSubview:lblUserName];
[vis addSubview:txtUserName];
[vis setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:vis];
```

Regards,

Amit

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. I am sure this will help you.

```
UILabel *lblLeft = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30)];
lblLeft.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblLeft.text = @"Name: ";
lblLeft.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
lblLeft.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

txtYourTextField.leftView = lblLeft;
```

Happy Coding :)

Deepak

Answer (score -2):

For quick solution, do that with two overlapping textfields like this:

[image]

Then change the textfield border style to `No border` style and disable the user interaction of the below textfield:

[image]